# How to push code from local machine to bonobo git server

Tags: git, github, bonobo

I need to do code changes and push that changes into **bonobo** git server(master branch).

Is there any way to do it directly from the UI(we haven't seen any edit option in the UI just like azure devops and github) or any other alternative way to accomplish this?

Note: I am not having any clue regarding this **bonobo** git server.

Answer (score 2):

You can check for ***git url*** somewhere in UI which we can use that for cloning via **git clone** command. Once cloned, then code will be available in our local machine where we can do changes like altering existing or adding new files etc., After code changes, then we can able to do checkout to another branch if required, adding those code changes, checking the status, committing as well as the final push of that change.

*Attached below git codes as example-*

**git clone 'git-url'**
*-->after clone, go to files/folder path for checkout and all.
-->try simple clone, if not worked then try for username alone and username with password.*

**git checkout -b 'new-branch-name'**
*--> create new branch and switch to it.*

(OR)

**git checkout 'existing-branch-name'**
*--> switch to existing branch.*

**git status**

**git add .**
*--> . means adding all changes.*

**git status**

**git commit -m "made changes"**
*-->we can add our comments here*

**git push origin 'branch-name'**

Since bonobo git server is also git supported, so that we can approach like above way-one of the alternative.